# Webpack Cannot Resolve node_modules lazy assets

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, monorepo

I'm working on a vuejs project and we're trying to use external vue cli applications as libraries. In these libraries we want to be able to export a router config, which lazy loads the components within one of these modules. However when we compile this using the vue-cli-service into a library and it's got lazy chunk assets we cannot resolve them with webpack.

I have a feeling its something to do with the public path, or some simple configuration but i'm just stuck and banging my head against a wall at this stage with it.

https://github.com/EvanBurbidge/mono-repo-tester

Here's a simple overview of what we're doing

```
App1 -> main app, installs App2, imports { router } from 'app2'
App2 -> library, compiles to common js lib exports router config
```

The console output from app1 
[image: see_screenshot_1]
The router configuration from app2
[image: see_screenshot_2]
The router importing app2 from app1
[image: see_screenshot_3]

> `/* config.module.rule('js') */
>         {
>           test: /\.jsx?$/,
>           exclude: [
>             function () { /* omitted long function */ }
>           ],
>           use: [
>             /* config.module.rule('js').use('cache-loader') */
>             {
>               loader: 'cache-loader',
>               options: {
>                 cacheDirectory: '/Users/evan/test/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader',
>                 cacheIdentifier: '39e7e586'
>               }
>             },
>             /* config.module.rule('js').use('babel-loader') */
>             {
>               loader: 'babel-loader'
>             }
>           ]
>         },`

Comment: Could you show webpack config?

Comment: hi @Styx its a vue cli application, so this is the config that comes with it. I've posted the js config above

Comment: I meant `entry` and `output` from webpack config (if you changed them).

Comment: Hi @Styx i've not changed anything, it's still just the basic vue cli webpack configuration.

Comment: And how exactly did you install `app2` as dependency of `app1`? `npm link` or local dependency?

Comment: using yalc, installs it as though it were a npm package, so i've got app2 compiled into a commonjs, umd.js file types. It's then installed as a dist folder, package.json, README.md in node_modules of app1. https://github.com/EvanBurbidge/mono-repo-test that's a quick version of what i'm using. @Styx

Comment: Can you add `./components/HelloWorld.vue` to your `app1` to see if that file will be imported? For the given github example, I can't see `app1` or `app2` content, so it's hard to test out different things. Can you create github with minimal code and setup in readme so we can test this out?

Comment: hi @ljubadr github.com/EvanBurbidge/mono-repo-test

Comment: I'm not able to see the content of folders `app1` or `app2`, just `.idea` folder... Check the repository in incognito mode

Comment: @ljubadr sorry about that, try this link https://github.com/EvanBurbidge/mono-repo-tester

Comment: In you github example, where is the file located where you construct the router?

Comment: The github example appears to be completely useless..There is no `webpack.conf.js` or `vue.conf.js` or `router.js` or really any source pertaining to the issue in question.

Comment: I've now updated the repo, apologies about that, turns out the network cut out when I left it pushing. https://github.com/EvanBurbidge/mono-repo-tester @Ferrybig app2/src/router.js is where the routes are constructed.  theres not much to the vue.conf.js just a libraryExport: "default" option set.

Comment: I got the same problem with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234533/vuejs-lazy-loading-error-components-used-are-a-web-components-this-i-uploaded-t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

It appears that you're suffering from the fact that the default config of webpack bundled with VueJS does not support what you are trying to accomplish. In fact, it may very well be that *Webpack* does not support what you are trying to accomplish [#2471](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2471) [#6818](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6818) [#7843](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7843).

When you compile app2 into UMD and try to use it within app1 by importing the UMD, the dynamic imports of app2 are not being resolved and are thus not copied over to the `publicPath` of app1. Since it is a dynamic import, compilation succeeds to the point where you can deploy the app. When you try to load the app however, it starts complaining that chunks are missing.

Here's one way to solve this problem:

`app2/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "app2",
  ...
  "main": "src/router.js"
}
```

`app2/src/router.js`

```
const Hey = () => import(/*webpackChunkName: 'app2.Hello.vue' */ './components/HelloWorld.vue')

export default [
  {
    path: '/app2',
    component: Hey,
    name: 'app2.hey'
  }
]
```

`app1/router.js`

```
import app2Router from 'app2'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

export default new Router([
  mode: 'history',
  ...
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    ...app2Router
  ]
])
```

By marking the `main` or `module` of `app2/package.json` as `router.js` instead of the the UMD bundle, you are forcing app1 to build the whole dependency graph and include any dynamic import that is detected. This in turn causes the dependencies to be copied over properly.

You could also achieve the exact same results by using

```
import app2Router from 'app2/src/router'
```

Comment: Had the same issue with dynamic svg icons.
What I ended up doing was: `import "my-library/lib/my-library.umd.icons"`

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, this issue is now fixed in Webpack 5 https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11127